# for loop in C error

Tags: c, visual-c++

Coding IDE: Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || i==6)
            {
                // print *****
                if(j<4)
                {
                    printf("*");
                }
                else if(j==4)
                {
                    printf("*\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(j==0)
                    printf("*");
                else if(j==4)
                {
                    printf("*\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces this error message：

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
```

I just don't know the reason why it gives me this kind of error msg. It suppose to be an easy for loop - `for (int i=0; i<10; i++){}` but it just doesn't work and gives me this kind of error msg.

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: @user1145976: How about posting real code?

Comment: VSC++ is old right? It may need declarations in the beginning of the functions.

Comment: The code that you provided doesn't include the line `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)` and [compiles, links & runs fine under GCC](http://ideone.com/1FJNC). Are you sure you're posting the exact code with which you're having a problem?

Comment: Declaring iterator `i` in  the loop is supported in `C99`, maybe your version of VC doesn't support it or you need to do something extra to compile it with `C99` support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that your compiler follows an older version of the C standard, ISO 9899:1990, commonly known as "C90" (or sometimes "C89" or "ANSI-C").

The C90 standard does not allow variable declarations inside for loops. All variable declarations must be done at the top of the current statement, directly after a `{`.

Further, the C90 standard does not allow `//` comments, which is likely the source of your compiler error.

The current C standard ISO 9899:2011 ("C11") allows variable declarations everywhere and also `//` comments.

Comment: Today, I set up win32 console application workspace for Microsoft Visual Studio 6.0,copy and paste the code, then it works...weird. 
I was create hello.c first, then using the default workspace seting, then I got this for loop error... so far still no clue what was going on... I will check the default setting compiler version...thanks !